# i have a problem with using __getattribute__

Tags: python

I have a school task that i need to do. I should create an object when constructor where when you put a list as an argument it only takes the string from the list and put them in the attribute of the class. When you try to print the list, it should only print the first characters of each string in the list. For example, if i put `[1,2,3,4,"something","word"]` the attribute should contain `["something","word"]` and when you print it on the console it should pop up sw. I must use `__getattribute__`.

This is the code that I wrote

```
class Myclass:

    def __init__(self, L):
        self.lst = []
        self.txt = ""

        if type(L) == list:
            for i in range(len(L)):
                if type(L[i]) == str:
                    self.lst.append(L[i])

            for i in range(len(self.lst)):
                self.txt += self.lst[i][0]

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "lst":
            return object.__getattribute__(self, "txt")
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


objA = Myclass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "something", "word"])
print(objA.lst)
print(objA.txt)
```

it gives me AttribureError:

```
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python\book2\unit2\project6.py", line 25, in <module>
    objA = Myclass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "something", "word"])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\python\book2\unit2\project6.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.lst.append(L[i])
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append
```

Comment: You made it so that accessing `self.lst` actually returns `self.txt`, but that is a string, so it doesn't have an `append` method.

Comment: Can you show your exact task description?

Answer (score 1):

I made attribute private. `__getattribute__` method is used in both cases: creating object and accessing by `print(objA.lst)`.

In the case of creating object, `self._lst.append(item)` calls `__getattribute__` under the hood. Like `self.__getattribute__('_lst')`

```
class Myclass:

    def __init__(self, L):
        self._lst = []  # private attribute to hold the list of strings
        self.txt = ""

        if isinstance(L, list):
            for item in L:
                if isinstance(item, str):
                    self._lst.append(item)
                    self.txt += item[0]

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "lst":
            return object.__getattribute__(self, "txt")
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    objA = Myclass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "something", "word"])
    print(objA.lst)  # prints 'sw'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use range on lists, just enumerate the list. As follows:

```
class Myclass():

def __init__(self, L):
    self.txt = ""

    if type(L) == list:
        for s in L:
            if type(s) == str:
                self.txt += s[0:1]

def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if name == "lst":
        return object.__getattribute__(self, "txt")
    else:
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


objA = Myclass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "something", "word", ""])
print(objA.lst)
print(objA.txt)
```

Comment: For those reading along at home, what's unique about this answer is that he has not kept the list.  If the class never needs to refer to the original list, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have solved this in reverse.  You do not need to construct the "txt" attribute, because that's exactly how lists print themselves.  Consider:

```
class Myclass:

    def __init__(self, L):
        self.lst = []

        if type(L) == list:
            for i in L:
                if type(i) == str:
                    self.lst.append(i)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "txt":
            lst =  object.__getattribute__(self, "lst")
            return ''.join(l[0] for l in lst)
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


objA = Myclass([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "something", "word"])
print(objA.lst)
print(objA.txt)
```

Output:

```
['something', 'word']
sw
```

Note that your design doesn't work if you add to `lst` later, whereas this design will.

Comment: That works but it does not print the first characters

Comment: That was not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion most elegant and readable way to accomplish that is by overriding *collections UserList* init and all methods that takes care of adding elements + the one for getting list to only return first letters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).